# ffmpeg integration error in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ffmpeg

i use [URL](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone/comment-page-1#comment-1116) to extract frames from Movie for iphone. but i get error like "ld: library not found for -lavformat" in sumulator.any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the ffmpeg library that is provided with that example.

Comment: you have to cross-compile for the arm, See ffmpeg docs about that